# Como enmascarar URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

Tengo un sitio en WordPress dentro de un subdirectorio en el *public_html* del hosting.

He redireccionado el dominio apuntando a ese subdirectorio desde el .htaccess del root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!carpeta/)(.*)$ carpeta/$1 [L,NC]
```

Lo que quiero es que al cargar el sitio no se vea ese nombre del subdirectorio en la barra de direcciones, es decir, que lo que esta en *.com.ar/carpeta* se vea *.com.ar* . ¿Es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Mirlo. Hay varias maneras de cambiar tu URL y una de ellas es usando el panel de control.

- En el menú de administración, ve a Configuración > General para
  entrar a la pantalla de configuración general desde donde puedes
  actualizar tanto la dirección de WordPress como la de tus archivos
  centrales de Wordpress.
- La segunda forma más común de cambiar la URL de WordPress es en el
  archivo wp-config.php. El archivo wp-config.php se encuentra en el
  directorio raíz de tu sitio de WordPress y se puede acceder a él a
  través de FTP, SSH o WP-CLI. En tu archivo wp-config.php, añade estas dos líneas en algún lugar por encima de la línea que te dice que dejes de editar:

  `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );`

  `define( 'WP_SITEURL', ‘http://yoursiteurl.com' );`
- Un tercer método que puedes usar para cambiar tu URL de WordPress es
  directamente en la base de datos de WordPress. Para ello, utilizas
  phpMyAdmin.Esto se hace normalmente como último recurso.

Espero que esto sea de utilidad.

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien; eso sería si quiero mover el directorio de la instalación, verdad? Lo que busco es algo "estético", que cuando alguien ingrese al sitio no vea ese /carpeta al final de la URL que le aparece en la barra del explorador pero manteniendo los archivos en ese directorio. Gracias.